# How can I count the amount of times a name appears?

Tags: javascript, jquery, count

This is what I am trying to do:

I have an API response that contains a field with names.  I am successfully able to get the response but using JavaScript I want to count how many times a name repeats.  For example:

```
<span class="person_name">John</span>
<span class="person_name">John</span>
<span class="person_name">Stefany</span>
<span class="person_name">Steven</span>
<span class="person_name">Steven</span>
```

I want to be able to count that John appears 2 times, Stefany appears 1 time, and Steven appears 2 times.

What have I tried so far?

```
$(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "API_CALL",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function (results) {
                    var imagesArray = new Array();
                    var allMedia = results.data._embedded.media;
                    for (var i = 0; i < allMedia.length; i++) {
                        var media1 = allMedia[i];
                        var imagesHtml = "<div id='person_item'>";
                        imagesHtml += "<span class='person_name'>{0}
</span>".replace("{0}", media1._embedded.person.name);
                        imagesHtml += "</div>";
                        imagesArray.push(media1.images.square);

                        $("#list").append(imagesHtml);
                    }
                    var numItems = $('.person_name').length
    console.log(numItems);
                }

            });

});
```

Comment: what you want ? you just want the that you have a string like "John John Stefany Steven Steven" which have space separated name. And in that string the occurrence of each name..

Comment: How do you plan on using this data. There are several ways to do this. The right one depends on the what kind of data structure is best suited to how you will use it. For instance: do you just need the data to for a single string that states this, or in @each #person_item do you want to display the name count next to each name? Or... you get the picture

Comment: @MukeshAgarwal Thanks for replying.  The names are in spans.  I just updated my description.

Comment: @Charlie What i want to do is count how many times a person appears and then I want to order the names based on how many times the person appears from highest to lowest.  Sort of like a leader board.

Comment: So to confirm, You want to sort the data based on frequency (of occurance) strength. Then lay the data to the DOM

Comment: @Charlie Yes, that's right.  I would like to count the frequency and then arrange the names from those who appear the most to the least.

Comment: Each name only appearing once in the final (displayed) list, I assume. Ne?

Comment: Please include expected behaviour in question itself

Answer (score 1):

```
var results = {
    data: {
        _embedded: {
            media: [{
                _embedded: {
                    person: {name : 'John'}
                }
            },
            {
                _embedded: {
                    person: {name : 'John'}
                }
            },
            {
                _embedded: {
                    person: {name : 'Stefany'}
                }
            },
            {
                _embedded: {
                    person: {name : 'Steven'}
                }
            },
            {
                _embedded: {
                    person: {name : 'Steven'}
                }
            },{
                _embedded: {
                    person: {name : 'Steven'}
                }
            }]
        }
    }
};

var allMedia = results.data._embedded.media;
var countNames = {};
var name;
for (var i = 0; i < allMedia.length; i++) {
    var media1 = allMedia[i];
    name = media1._embedded.person.name;
    countNames[name]  = countNames.hasOwnProperty(name) ? ++countNames[name] : 1;
}
console.log(countNames);
```

we create a variable for counting frequency of name and update this variable for each  name in array

Comment: Thanks.  Can you provide a JSfiddle example? When I use this I am getting this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: thanks but how do i then show the person with the most first and then the others in descending order?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this, hope it all what you want

```
var numItems = $('.person_name').length;
 var name = [];
 var occ =[];
 for(var i=0;i<numItems.length;i++)
 {
    if(occ[numItems[i].val())
    {
       occ[numItems[i]++;
    }
    else
    {
       name.push(numItems[i].val());
       occ[numItems[i].val()] = 1;
    }
 }
```

Now you have single instance of name in name array and there corresponding occurence in occ array